# When hit the home page url, it shows contact us page as home page

Tags: redirect, magento2.2.6, cms-pages, home-page

I am facing a very unusual scenario for my web site. (https://zitomer.com)

When we try to access homepage https://zitomer.com it displays contact us page as a homepage.

What will be the issue? I am using magento 2.2.6

Comment: Check server level (apache, nginx or htaccess) config files also for any re-direction.

Comment: Also check in Admin Marketing => SEO & Search > URL Rewrites for any redirection

Comment: Hi mohammad, all configuration for Marketing => SEO & Search > URL Rewrites for any redirection is correct in backend. BUt still getting this issue

Comment: check your htaccess file. Is there any 301 redirection to contact us page

Comment: No there is no any 301 redirection to contact us page

Comment: go to admin -> store -> configuration -> general -> web and check here :https://prnt.sc/mgs195 . Is there homepage selected ?

Comment: Zitomer is our home pgae. Yes, I have set "Zitomer" as a home page. please check the https://prnt.sc/mgs870

Comment: Please change store and check if you have multiple store. Also flush the cache

Comment: we have only default store

Answer (score 0):

There is no redirect, your home page `https://www.zitomer.com/` display a contact form that it's not the same as the contact page `https://www.zitomer.com/contact-us`. Check the content of your homepage what you're displaying (cms page, xml etc...)